# I defined a method but still getting an error 'rails undefined method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing an authentication application. I have this code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "User Sign Up"    
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    sign_in_check @user
    if @user.save
      #flash[:status] = true
      #flash[:alert] = "You have successfully signed up!!"
      #sign_in_check @user
      redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :success => "Welcome to the Bakeshop"}
    else
      @title = "User Sign Up" 
      render 'new'
    end  
  end
end
```

This is a simple sign-up code, and whenever I try and sign up, rails returns an error:

```
undefined method `sign_in_check' for #<UsersController:0x68c0a90>
```

but I defined a method `sign_in_check` in my `Users_helper.rb`:

```
module UsersHelper
  def sign_in_check(user)
    #some stuff to enable session
  end
end
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is your method is a helper. Helpers will be available in views with matching name by default, but not open to controllers without setting.

Two ways to fix:

1. Allow this helper in UsersController

   ```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
     helper :user #This will expose UsersHelper module to UsersController
   ```
2. Instead, put this method into ApplicationController. I would prefer this due to the method's nature.

Comment: Oh so that's why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Include your `UserHelper` in your `UserController` as follows and you should be able to use any methods defined within the helper.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UsersHelper

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually put in the application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def sign_in_check(user)
    #some stuff to enable session
  end

end
```

Helpers are used for views.  If you want to use it in both - you can do that, but that doesn't sound like what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

just include your helper module in your controller

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
     helper :user 
   ...
  end
```

Thanks